# ReSharper, Stylecop and sorting mix-cased usings alpabetically

Tags: c#, coding-style, resharper, log4net, stylecop

I use ReSharper to format code and StyleCop for code analyses, and I use rule `SA1210:UsingDirectivesMustBeOrderedAlphabeticallyByNames`.

Everything was fine until `StructureMap` and `log4net` met in the same file: ReSharper sorts them case-sensitively:

```
using StructureMap;

using log4net;
```

But StyleCop checks them case-insensitively:

```
error : SA1210: Using directives must be sorted alphabetically by the namespaces.
```

I don't want to turn off rule. I wouldn't use StyleCop plugin for ReSharper as it proved to be unstable in my environment and slows machine a lot.

How can I make them work together?

Comment: Set the rule to give just a warning not an error.

Comment: It's not an option for me - nobody fix warnings, but everyone have to fix failing build.

Comment: Can't you ignore the ReSharper rule? You'll have to sort the directives manually, but if you really want it that way, that's probably what you have to do.

Comment: No, I want make them work to help me: I get used to `Shift+Ctrl+Alt+F` in resharper to reformat code and I don't want to waste time on what can be done automatically; and I want StyleCop to force team members to do the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could alias the log4net using statement:

```
using Log4Net = log4net;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private Log4Net.ILog log;
        public Class1()
        {
            log = Log4Net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (Class1));
            log.Debug("msg");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, and I think it's acceptable workaround for my purposes - thanks!